# Pronoms personnels (je, nous, on) à utiliser dans un rapport

Tags: pronoms-personnels, style-de-rédaction

Y a-t-il une bonne référence avec les conseils pour l'utilisation des pronoms personnels dans un rapport (par exemple rapport de projet ou dissertation) ? Le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle.

Une recherche avec Google trouve beaucoup de conseils anecdotiques [[1]](http://www.vn.refer.org/science-action/IMG/pdf/doc-3.pdf), [[2]](http://www.anglaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=18&msg=29421&titre=Nous/On/Je???), [[3]](http://www.doc-etudiant.fr/Francais-qr/Pour-la-redaction-dun-rapport-dois-je-utiliser-le-pronom-je-on-ou-nous-60358.html), [[4]](http://devoirs.fr/francais/quel-personne-utiliser-pour-ecrire-une-dissertation-je-nous-on-133828.html), qui parfois se contredisent. Un ancien prof m'avait donné une règle simple : éviter le *je*. Mais ce n'est pas si simple que ça !

Il est clairement mieux d'éviter *je* dans les cas où ça nuit à l'objectivité, par exemple

> Je pense que la mauvaise qualité des pièces est la raison…

Il vaut mieux dire

> La mauvaise qualité des pièces est la raison…

De manière générale, utiliser *nous* à la place de *je* n'est pas une solution, surtout quand il n'y a qu'un seul auteur.

> Nous présentons les éléments…

Cela semble incohérent. Par contre, le pronom *nous* semble acceptable dans un cas comme

> Nous pouvons voir à la figure 1 que…

car le *nous* est le lecteur et l'auteur ensemble. Mais le pronom *on* est souvent utilisé de la même façon, mais est-ce acceptable ?

> On peut voir à la figure 1 que…

Il est possible d'éviter tout pronom ainsi

> La figure 1 illustre…

Est-ce que le pronom *je* peut tout de même être utilisé dans certains cas où c'est l'auteur qui a fait quelque chose dans le contexte du projet? C'est un fait, par exemple

> Après la première itération du projet, j'ai effectué des tests.

Il est possible de changer cet exemple à une forme passive (le sujet est ambigu) pour éviter le *je*, mais est-ce mieux ?

> Après la première itération du projet, des tests ont été effectués.

Comment: Il est malheureusement vrai que certains indécis, le cul entre deux chaises, finissent leur rapport à *je nous*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'ai enfin trouvé une référence qui a de bonnes explications. C'est le [Guide de rédaction du rapport de fin d'études : 
conseils de rédaction de l'École de technologie supérieure](http://accros.etsmtl.ca/Rapports/findetudes/rapport_fin_etudes/guide_redaction.pdf). À la [section 1.8](http://accros.etsmtl.ca/Rapports/findetudes/rapport_fin_etudes/guide_redaction.pdf#page=17) sur les pronoms, on trouve :

> Pronoms à éviter
>
> De façon générale, dans un rapport technique, il faut éviter l’emploi du « je », du « tu », trop 
>   personnels, voire prétentieux, et qui livrent des traits d’affectivité non pertinents pour le style 
>   technique.
>
> Même le « nous » dit « de modestie » ne peut être utilisé que pour représenter un groupe 
>   de personnes, une équipe de travail et non un seul et unique rédacteur. À moins de vouloir 
>   insister, par exemple, très spécifiquement, sur le choix des auteurs du rapport, le « nous » 
>   est à bannir dans un rapport technique. De plus, les références à ces différents pronoms 
>   comme dans « notre étude », « votre compréhension du sujet vous sera ainsi facilitée » 
>   sont à proscrire.
>
> Le « vous », qui interpelle le lecteur du rapport, ne peut être employé, car il livre une 
>   intention didactique visant à enseigner ou à instruire de la véracité d’un propos. Par 
>   ailleurs, le « il » et le « ils » ne peuvent servir que de rappels d’un nom au pluriel, non à 
>   parler de personnes.
>
> Il ne semble rester que le « on », pronom indéfini par excellence, paraît-il… Lorsque ce 
>   pronom renvoie à plusieurs personnes, un « nous », il est alors d’usage familier et est à 
>   éviter dans le style technique. Le seul moment où le pronom « on » est de bon usage est 
>   lorsqu’il rappelle une situation générale ou des personnes sans les identifier. La phrase 
>   suivante le prouve : « On a observé de multiples tornades dans le ciel californien ».
>
> Pronoms à considérer
>
> La forme impersonnelle en « il » comme dans « Il faudra respecter les normes 
>   environnementales. » et la phrase nominale « Les normes environnementales devront être 
>   respectées. » résolvent bien des problèmes de rédaction. Plus encore, ces genres de 
>   phrases gardent l’attention du lecteur sur l’objet d’étude du rapport et non sur les rédacteurs 
>   ou les destinataires éventuels.
>
> Pour s’en convaincre, il suffit de comparer ces six phrases où la dernière version
>   correspond entièrement au style technique ou scientifique.
>
> - Je crois que la position idéale pour le réservoir se situe à l’arrière du marqueur.
> - Nous croyons que la position idéale pour le réservoir se situe à l’arrière du marqueur.
> - Vous comprendrez que la position idéale pour le réservoir se situe à l’arrière du 
>     marqueur.
> - On peut constater que la position idéale pour le réservoir se situe à l’arrière du 
>     marqueur.
> - Il est facile de constater que la position idéale pour le réservoir se situe à l’arrière du 
>     marqueur.
> - **La position idéale pour le réservoir se situe à l’arrière du marqueur.**

Answer (score 4):

Le style dépend beaucoup du domaine, mais dans beaucoup de cas, on conseille d'éviter au maximum les pronoms personnels. C'est presque toujours possible, même si ça force parfois à faire quelques pirouettes.

Dans le cas où un pronom ne peut pas être évité, *on* passe mieux que *nous* et *je* est plutôt mal vu. J'écrirais donc

> La figure 1 illustre…

et

> Après la première itération du projet, des tests ont été effectués.

par contre, même s'il n'y a qu'un seul auteur, on peut très bien écrire au pluriel quand on utilise *on* et *nous*.

Cela étant, il n'y a rien de catastrophique dans tes autres propositions et tu peux très bien choisir d'utiliser des pronoms, voire de décrire à la première personne ce que tu as fait.