# "Nous" versus "on" in a thesis?

Tags: sujet, style-de-rédaction

I would like to know *how and when* to use "on", "nous", and "je" in a thesis for a master degree?

For example which one is more correct?

> Dans ce chapitre, on va voir, …
>
> Dans ce chapitre, nous allons voir, …
>
> Ce chapitre présente les résultats que j'ai obtenu, …

If you have any reference that would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pronoms personnels (je, nous, on) à utiliser dans un rapport](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/pronoms-personnels-je-nous-on-%c3%a0-utiliser-dans-un-rapport)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make this useful distinction :

1) using *on* as a substitute for first plural person (*nous*)

> Dépêche-toi, on va être en retard !

This is constantly used in oral casual contexts, but is clearly **off-limits in a master degree**! If you have to use *nous* as a polite way to say *I* in your thesis, like in your example (*Dans ce chapitre, nous allons voir...*), go for it and don't use *on* there. The possiblity to use first person in your work is, I guess, another subject.

2) using *on* to designate an undefined subject

> On a sonné à la porte.

This is **not only possible, it's the only way** in some domains, like mathematics, as fkraiem pointed out in an earlier comment, but not only science. To give another example out of science, in philosophy there will be *many* times for the use of *on* (Peut-on rire de tout ? Doit-on craindre la mort ?).

Answer (score 2):

En général il faut éviter d'utiliser des termes comme "on" car ils sont trop impersonnels alors que toi tu présentes ton travail. Dans ton cas, il serait préférable d'utiliser le "nous" à sa place. "Nous" comme formule de politesse.
En présentation verbale, tu pourras utiliser la formule en "je" mais pas en écrit.

Comment: Cela dépend peut-être des domaines... En mathématiques, *on* est de rigueur.