# “On” vs “nous” in spoken French

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, conjonctions, formulation-idiomatique, langage-informel

Do people prefer to use ***on*** in everyday speaking, even in formal situations? Or will they use ***nous***?

For example, if you are at a gathering and you say *"**Nous sommes** si chanceux d'être ici"*. Would that express more formality than using ***on est***?

Or would it just sound strange spoken like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do people prefer to use on in everyday speaking, even in formal situations?

***On*** as a first person plural subject has almost replaced ***nous*** in everyday conversation but the more formal the context is, the more you'll hear ***nous***.

> For example, if you are at a gathering and you say "Nous sommes si chanceux d'être ici". Would that express more formality than using on est?

Yes, that would express more formality although not excessive formality. Nobody will frown upon you if you say this.

Note that the ***on***/***nous*** dilemma is a recurrent topic here. Have a look to these questions:

[Spécificités de l'utilisation de « on »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/sp%C3%A9cificit%C3%A9s-de-lutilisation-de-on/6292#6292)

["Nous" versus "on" in a thesis?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11241/nous-versus-on-in-a-thesis)

["Nous on sera les bons"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/nous-on-sera-les-bons)

[Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-on-au-lieu-de-nous)

[Dois-je utiliser « on » ou « nous » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/871/dois-je-utiliser-on-ou-nous)

[« On » remplace « nous » : quel nom pour ce processus ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/72/on-remplace-nous-quel-nom-pour-ce-processus)

Comment: should flag the question as duplicate instead

Comment: Je dois dire que jamais de la vie je dirais (pauvre anglophone que je suis) Nous sommes "si chanceux de" qui fait calque de l'anglais: to be lucky. Avoir de la chance, quelle chance...etc. (Et on n'utilise pas le verbe eclipse comme cela en anglais, sois dit en passant).

Comment: @Lambie Merci pour *eclipse*. Je n'ai pas repris *être si chanceux de* car d'une part, l'expression semble d'un usage courant au Québec et d'autre part, même si l'expression peut faire penser à une forme d'anglicisme, *être chanceux* est attesté depuis longtemps en français: *Cet homme est si chanceux, qu'il a eu deux billets noirs à cette lotterie*, 1690, Furetière et ne pose aucun de problème de compréhension. (PS: jamais de la vie je **ne** dirais;  **soit** dit en passant).

Comment: Qu'est-ce qu'un billet noire? Comme des billets gagnants? Franchement l'expression 'si chanceux de' ... j'ai inventé. Je ne sais pas si c'est correct ou non...

Comment: *Billet noir* ne se dit plus aujourd'hui mais c'était bien un billet gagnant au dix-septième siècle. La phrase est correcte. Une alternative plus habituelle serait *Nous avons beaucoup de chance d'être ici / On a beaucoup de chance d'être ici*