# Grammaire: habitude vs. une fois

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps

Regardez les phrases suivantes en anglais:

Habitude: *We go to the cinema on Fridays.*

Une fois: *We're going to the cinema on Friday.*

> Est-il vrai qu'en Français, les deux phrases ont
>   la même traduction ?

C'est à dire :

Habitude ou une fois : Nous allons au cinéma le dimanche.

Si c'est le cas, on n'a aucun moyen de savoir si le locuteur veut dire qu'il va au cinéma cette semaine ou s'il y va tous les vendredis.

Answer (score 8):

Pour reprendre l'exemple que tu as cité,

Habitude : "Nous allons au cinéma *le* dimanche"

Une fois : "Nous allons au cinéma dimanche"

Comme tu peux le voir, la nuance s'exprime assez différement en français. La présence de l'article *le* signife que tu vas au cinéma "*le* dimanche" (habituel).

Comment: Est-ce que vous êtes francophone de langue maternelle?

Comment: Oui, je suis francophone, de langue maternelle.

Answer (score 4):

- *On va au cinéma **le** vendredi :*  When we go to the movies, that's on Fridays.
- *On va au cinéma **les** vendredis  :*  We go to the movies on Fridays.
- *On va au cinéma **tous les** vendredis / chaque vendredi :*  We go to the movies every Friday.
- *On va au cinéma **ce** vendredi  :*  We go to the movies this Friday (next Friday).
- *On va au cinéma **vendredi**  :*  Idem.

Note: in real life conversation or casual writing, we use *on* instead of *nous* as first person plural. See [“On” vs “nous” in spoken French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28032/on-vs-nous-in-spoken-french)

Comment: Est-ce que vous êtes francophone de langue maternelle?

Comment: Je demande parce que je crois que Duolingo pense que le pluriel „les vendredis“ est faux.

Comment: Les jours de la semaines ne sont pas invariables en français. Le pluriel ne peut être considéré comme faux que quand il s'agit de plusieurs jours de la même semaine: *On va au cinéma **les lundi et vendredi** de la semaine prochaine*. C'est probablement le cas avec Duolingo.

Comment: Oui, ma langue maternelle est le français.