# Utilisation de "on+ le présent de 3e personne" au lieu d'utiliser "nous"

Tags: grammaire

Quelle est l'expression qui est correcte:

**les équations que l'on obtient** ou **les équations que nous obtenons**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> les équations que l'on obtient
>
> les équations que nous obtenons
>
> les équations qu'on obtient

Ces trois phrases sont toutes correctes (All of these sentences are correct).

Pour citer l'utilisateur (To quote the user) @jlliagre

> À la première personne du pluriel, le sujet *on* a presque remplacé *nous* dans la conversation courante, mais plus le contexte est formel, plus *nous* s'entend.

(*On* as a first person plural subject has almost replaced *nous* in everyday conversation but the more formal the context is, the more you'll hear *nous*.)

Lire cette excellente réponse : (Read this excellent answer:)

[“On” vs “nous” in spoken French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28032/on-vs-nous-in-spoken-french)

NB

Les registres dans lesquels on utilise régulièrement le *on* de la 1ère personne du pluriel n'utilisent pour ainsi dire jamais l'allomorphe *l'on*. (merci @Eau qui dort).

[The registers in which one regularly uses the *on* of the 1st person of the plural never use the allomorph *l'on*]

Comment: Les registres dans lesquels on utilise régulièrement le *on* de la 1ère personne du pluriel n'utilisent pour ainsi jamais l'allomorphe *l'on*, note