# Is it correct to say "nous on est là"?

Tags: grammaire

Is it correct to say "nous on est là"? Or is it preferable to say "nous nous sommes là"? Why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The first one is very common and correct unless you pay attention to the overly conservative opinion of the *[Académie](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/moi-je-nous)*, the second one is less likely to be heard but equally valid French.

A comma (a pause) after the first pronoun is expected:

> Nous, on est là !

See [“On” vs “nous” in spoken French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28032)