# In french, when to use 'on' and when to use 'nous'

Tags: pronoms

I'm confused between on and nous . Since they share the same meaning

Comment: Have you tried researching the subject? There's tons of answers to that on the web already.

Comment: Yep, just there: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/quel-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-dusage-entre-nous-et-on

Comment: Il y a aussi https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13910/17649 et https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8185/17649

Answer (score 1):

Try all those questions and answers listed below; there has to be in them more than you can handle as well as the answer to your particular questions.

[Quel est la différence d'usage entre « nous » et « on » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4601/17649)
[Is it always ok to use “on” in place of “nous”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13910/17649)
[Use of “on” and personal pronouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8185/17649)
[Spécificités de l'utilisation de « on »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6289/17649)
[Pronoms personnels (je, nous, on) à utiliser dans un rapport](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5894/17649)
[Dois-je utiliser « on » ou « nous » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/871/17649)
[Pourquoi utilise-t-on « on » au lieu de « nous » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2737/17649)
[« On » remplace « nous » : quel nom pour ce processus ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/72/17649)

Among a quantity of sources that could be mentioned  (external to the FSE), I'll add this  one: "[« On », pronom imbécile,…](https://www.nicolas-hoffmann.net/source/1445-On-pronom-imbecile-definit-celui-qui-l-emploie.html)". It's a good sample of what certain French people think, although, to be sure, they are a minority.

Comment: +1 pour la dernière source : « On », pronom imbécile, définit celui qui l'emploie. (lol). Alors il me faut ne pas l'utiliser:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Non, pas du tout, il faut en prendre et en laisser ; ces personne qui se plaignent d'un usage abusif ont certainement raison ; par exemple on trouve dans l'article le cas des personnes qui pour vous parler utilisent ce pronom (« Comment va-t-on  ? » pour « Comment allez-vous ? »).

Comment: Cependant cet emploi (erroné?) est attesté dans le livre de Mauger dont je parle dans ma réponse. On, dans le français parlé (F.P.) familier peut être :

une première personne du pluriel :
Nous, on veut bien. On n'a pas gradé les cochons ensemble ! On prend notre café tous les midis.

une deuxième personne du singulier ou du pluriel :
Alors, on est content(s) ?

Comment: @dimitris À mon avis, « Nous, on veut bien. » n'est pas ce que qu'il y a de pire, bien que je préfèrerais la simplicité de l'anglais (Nous, nous voulons bien.) ; il faut quand même remarquer qu'en anglais cette répétition est évitée et que pour marquer la mise en valeur de la personne du verbe il faut utiliser dans le parler l'accentuation  et à l'écrit le soulignement (*We* really want it .).  Néanmoins, c'est surtout l'usage pour des remplacement aux autres personnes que la première du pluriel qui dérange ces gens-là et je trouve qu'ils ont raison.(champ 1)

Comment: @dimitris  Il y a ceux qui l'utilisent pour « je » ; c'est vraiment extrême . Pour une deuxième personne du singulier, ça se dit aussi mais il ne me viendrait pas à l'esprit de le dire ; il y a un certain point de vue impersonnel dans cette tournure qui ne me convient pas ; ne pas oublier que l'on utilise aussi  « on » pour les deuxièmes personnes avec plusieurs effet, dont l'un est un effet sarcastique ; il faut donc faire attention de bien s'en servir et de rester dans les limites d'une utilisation neutre (si on ne veut pas donner des impressions qui ne sont pas les nôtres). (fin)

Comment: Merci pour ces deux derniers commentaires !

Answer (score 1):

Source G. Mauger: [Grammaire pratique du français d'aujourd'hui](https://www.amazon.fr/GRAMMAIRE-PRATIQUE-FRANCAIS-DAUJOURDHUI-Langue/dp/2010021347/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1551786660&sr=8-1&keywords=Grammaire%20pratique%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%20d%27aujourd%27hui), Librairie Hachette (p. 152).

Ce pronom est l'équivalent, comme sujet, de *quelqu'un* :

> On vient.

Ou de *les gens*, *certains* :

On dit que...

Il a pour représentant, dans la même proposition *soi*, *se* :

> On a souvent besoin d'un plus petit que soi. On se nuit en agissant ainsi.

Dans une préposition différente, *vous* représente *on* :

> Si l'on lui demande cela, il vous répond que...

*On*, dans le français parlé (F.P.) familier peut être :

- une première personne du pluriel :

> Nous, on veut bien. On n'a pas gradé les cochons ensemble ! On prend notre café tous les midis.

- une deuxième personne du singulier ou du pluriel :

> Alors, on est content(s) ?

- une troisième personne du singulier ou du pluriel :

> Voilà ce que j'ai demandé. Mais on s'est contenté de sourire (On = il, elle, ou ils, elles).

Selon ce livre toujours les substituts de *on* sont :

- Vous (plutôt que nous) :

> Vous marchez parfois des heures dans ces pays, sans rencontrer âme qui vive (=on marche)

- F.P. Ils (Nota bene : je ne sais pas si ça contredit l'écriture inclusive:-) Le livre est vieux quand même.! )

> Ils ont encore augmenté les cigarettes !

- Les gens :

  > Les gens savent bien vous remettre à votre place !
- La forme pronominale à valeur passive :

  > Il se dit bien des sottises. Il se vend bien des livres. (On dit... ; On vend...)

Voir aussi

https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/understanding-french-on-subject-pronoun

http://cnrtl.fr/definition/on

et les questions déjà mentionnées dans les commentaires et l'autre réponse.